# SEO for a single page application with next and previous - Canonical strategy. I am using vue.js

Tags: seo, rel-canonical

This is not a SPA (single page application). It has different pages for categories but the filter on left (like amazon) is used for searching.
It shows 10 results in one page and has a `previous` and `next` link.
But since we are using vue.js, the filter results are fetched via AJAX and displayed without changing the url. Each result page has different content and there are `next` and `previous` links on them which search engines can crawl. These links are like

```
<link rel="next" href="main-url/page=2"/>
<link rel="prev" href="main-url/page=1"/>
```

The canonical on each page will be

```
<link rel=”canonical” href=”example-main-url″/>
```

Since the main URL is not changing, my question is

1. Is this something to be worried about? Even if the URL changes, my
   `next` & `previous` pages with canonical still point to main category
   page.
2. Do you guys suggest any changes to this strategy?

Should I try to change the URL by appending some parameters to the URL?

Update: I studies some more top ranked eCommerce sites other than amazon and got more confused. These sites on each page, had canonical link pointing back to their current page. example

```
 <link rel=”canonical” href=”main-url/page=1″/>
 <link rel=”canonical” href=”main-url/page=2″/>
```

Comment: Pagination adds no value to SEO.   Users rarely use it either.   I recommend getting rid of pagination entirely when possible.

Comment: Is this based on experience? I normally use it on eCommerce sites

Comment: Look at your stats.  Do you get any search engine referrals to pages 2+?   What percent of users go beyond page 1?   When I've done that analysis I've found that search engines don't refer enough traffic to pagination to count and that about 1% of users use pagination.     I've had much better luck with faceted navigation both for SEO and for usability.

Comment: Sorry that the question was not explanatory enough. I am building faceted search and this problem scenario is for faceted search.

Comment: I usually recommend not paginating facets.   If there are too many results, it is easier for users to apply another criteria rather than to visit many pages.